# Efficient way to search for autocomplete suggestions in a large array

Tags: javascript

I have a webapp with an input field which should be filled in with user's region according to [ISO3166-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-3166-2). To improve user experience I wanna make this field an autocomplete - user starts typing, and gets suggestions. There's also a country field, which, if filled, would limit the amount of regions to suggest to regions from the chosen country.

The regions list is a pretty large amount of data, which includes region names and codes for all officially recognized countries in the world and it's footprint is about 250kB.

Those of you, who had similar experience, which of the following ways to implement it would you recommend to achieve the best performance and why?

1) don't send the whole regions list to the client and make a request to server instead every time user types in region field (debounce it, ofcourse), so we look for suggestions server-side but have additional roundtrips;

2) use a webworker to find suggestions;

3) smth else?

Comment: For large dataset, it's better to retrieve data via ajax, there is a jquery library that might help. https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Comment: @KhorshedAlam thanks! I'm using react, so I'm not looking for jquery plugins, but I'm interested in general, do ajax requests are really worth it for data sets of such dimension?

Comment: Regardless of whether you choose to keep the data in the server or download it all for speed, I would construct it using a search tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree).

Answer (score 0):

You can have an associative array with keys as the region name (or somewhat similar), then you can have the array populated from the backend according the the logic.

1. Binary search the array using the typed keyword
2. If data exists then populate the autocomplete or else populate the array from backend data.

You have to write code to maintain the array yourself.

Or else you can save your time by using something like Twitter typeahead with Bloodhound having prefetching, intelligent caching, fast lookups, and backfilling with remote data.

Here's the link: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

Comment: Is it really more performant than regular `Array.prototype.find`?

Comment: Array.prototype.find was added in ECMAScript 2015 and may not be available in all browsers. However, if you look at the polyfill provided by MDN, it does linear search, whereas Binary search is faster.

Also, you can have a look at this link for search techniques: http://www.andygup.net/fastest-way-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array/

Comment: @amabkaycee - what if we want the autocomplete list to have the typed chars not only in the beginning but in the middle as well. e.g. Lets say the typed chars is 'abc'.  The autocomplete list should comprise of  'abcdef' and 'i love abc'.